# Why I can't fetch data from a api in javascript? It shows deploy created successfully. But while running in firebase cloud function, it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, fetch-api

I want to implement firebase cloud messaging via firebase cloud function so that I can send message to every users which have installed my android application. The message would be a value of a key of json object from this url <[https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/bangladesh]>.

Click the text below to see the image of json object
[json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCnDW.png)

In my case, I want to send the value of the key "todayDeaths" through firebase cloud message. When I try to call the json by api method and fetch the data of it and set this in message in index.js file, it showed no error and deploy created. But when I try to check the status of my function ,it shows error.

Click the text below to see the image of error showed in Logs of firebase cloud function.
[firebase cloud function Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g77Lt.png).

I will add the index.js code below:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);



exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun(async (context) 
=> {



const response=await axios.get(
    'https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries/bangladesh'
);
console.log(response.data);
const body=response.todayDeaths;

const message = {
    notification: {
        'title': 'Today death',
        'body': body,
    },
    topic:'allUser'
    
};


admin.messaging().send(message)
.then(response=>{
    console.log("Successfully sent",response);
}).catch(error=>{
    console.log("failed",response);
});


console.log('This will be run every 2 minutes!');
return null;
});
```

How can I solve the problem so that the firebase cloud messaging successfully send the message to all of the users of the project?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just forgot to import `axios`.

Add this to the top:

```js
const axios= require('axios');
```

Comment: After adding this on the top of function it shows an error in the .js file.  which is:Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        scheduledFunction(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:scheduledFunction"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

Comment: Can you pls check if there is a more specific error in the logs? Those erros usualy come when you try to deploy a function with syntax errors

Comment: I have added the function's code also.I didn't find any syntax errors. In my case, the error only shows when I add "const axios= require('axios'); ". I don't understand the reason

Comment: Did you install `axios` into your `functions` folder with: `npm i -S axios` ?